# Typescript / Jquery: accesing the class in a inner Jquery scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, scope, click

I searched all over stackoverflow and found alot of posts, so im pretty sure its duplicate, however i could not find any post that was noob friendly and clear to me, maybe because im pretty new to typescript.

What i am currently working with is typescript classes, and click in Jquery.
Normaly this or $(this) works for getting the Jquery item, but then againin TS this is normally reserved for the class:

When i use Jquery the this becomes replaced by the Jquery object.

So i am currently working with:

HTML:

```
<a data-id="6" class="js-set-crime-option btn btn-primary">Kies</a>
```

TS:

```
class Dealers
{
    constructor() {
        $(".js-set-crime-option").click(this.set);
    }

    public set() {
        var a = $(this);
        alert(a.data("id"));

        debugger;
        // i want to call test here
    }

    public test(id: string) {
        alert("helooooooo" + id);
    }

}
```

how can i call test in this scope?

EDIT: i found this not sure if it is the correct solution though

```
var me: Dealers;

class Dealers
{
    name:string = "friend";

    constructor() {
        $(".js-set-crime-option").click(this.set);
        me = this;
    }

    public set() {
        var a = $(this);
        me.test(a.data("id"));
    }

    public test(id: string) {
        alert("helooooooo" + id + this.name);
    }

}
```

Comment: "Normaly this or $(this) works for getting the Jquery item, but then againin TS this is normally reserved for the class" is not true. Furthermore, TypeScript classes are JavaScript classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the fat arrow notation to automatically preserve the correct 'this' but your suggestion should also work although it is safer to save this before attaching the handler .

```
element.click( () => { this.test(id); } );
```